# String.Substring in Swift 3 when start = end

Tags: swift, swift3, substring

I'm trying to do a simple thing actually - extract hard-coded parts of the string. For example from "123" I need "1", from "0123"- "01".
Now I've just read probably all tutorials on [pretty weird from my point of view] Range implementation in Swift, but still cannot get this simple code working as I want it to:

```
   let start2 = string.startIndex
   let end2 = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
   minutes = Int(string.substring(with: start2..<end2))
```

The problem is that in case of "123" start2 is equal to end2 and substring returns nil in this case. Any ideas?

P.S. Great gods, this operation was trivial even in assembler 20 years ago

Comment: The problem is not `substring()` (which returns an empty string in your case). But `Int("")` returns `nil` for an empty string. – What result do you expect if start2==end2 ?

Comment: What do i expect? 1 character of course

Comment: `..<` creates a *half-open* range which *excludes* the upper bound. With the closed range  `start2...end2` you would get one character.

Comment: Believe me or not I tried this. And got another compile error. :/

Comment: Also inventing a new operator in not justified for me in this case. We need more simple syntax, not more complex.

Comment: You are right, `substring(with:)` does not accept a closed range. So the solution in your case would simply be to subtract 2 from `endIndex` instead of 3. (`endIndex` is the "one-past the end" position.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to drop the last two characters.

There are multiple solutions. One is

```
let string = "0123"
let minutes = Int(String(string.characters.dropLast(2)))!
```

or

```
let range = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)..<string.endIndex
let minutes = Int(string.substring(to: range.lowerBound))!
```

And since you want `Int` anyway, why not simply

```
let minutes = Int(string)! / 100
```

Comment: What is the .lowerBound?  Part of the string left to the range?

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel Yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks you. Still I have no explanation how that Swift engineers invented a lot of new terms there, where things were straightforward and working the whole time :/

Comment: The main reason for using `<String.Index>` is Unicode compatibility where characters can have more than one byte.

Comment: That might be reasonable. I'm rather talking about breaking the basic concept - interval of indicies [2..2] is a character at position [2], not the empty sting, this is mathematics.